# Why does "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object" occur when trying to unpack tuples?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, tuples

I have this code:

```
list1 = [(1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9), (10, 11)]

for tup_obj in list1:
    if len(tup_obj) == 2:
        for a, b in tup_obj:
            print(a)
            print(b)
    elif len(tup_obj) == 3:
        for a, b, c in tup_obj:
            print(a)
            print(b)
            print(c)
    elif len(tup_obj) == 4:
        for a, b, c, d in tup_obj:
            print(a)
            print(b)
            print(c)
            print(d)
```

I need to unpack the tuples inside the list

```
list1 = [(1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9), (10, 11)]
```

It consists of tuples with different numbers of elements.

I'm trying to take each item in the list (i.e., nothing but the tuple), and once it is selected I want to check how many elements there are inside that tuple (for example, here in first case the number elements inside the tuple is 2).

This I did with the built-in `len` functions. So if it's two I'm going to take the value as `a, b` and if the selected tuple contains 3 or 4 elements it means I'm going to take the variable as `a, b, c` or `a, b, c, d`. But once this step is completed it's telling that it cannot unpack non iterable int object. But I don't know why.

Comment: are you sure you mean to iterate like `for a, b in tup_obj:` it seems you just want to assign each tup value which would be done as `a, b = tup_obj`

Comment: Please add stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out in the comments, you should do:

```
for tup_obj in list1:
    if len(tup_obj) == 2:
        a, b = tup_obj
        print(a)
        print(b)
# ...
```

But the whole convoluted construction seems unnecessary. Why not just:

```
for tup_obj in list1:
    for a in tup_obj:
        print(a)
```

That will cover all the cases dynamically.

Comment: This is the way to go if you want to have such a data structure.

Answer (score 0):

based on your code it looks like you want to assign the tuple values to a, b....etc rather than iterate over the tuple.

when you say `for a, b in tup_obj` this will take your tuple lets say (1,2). It will take the first item `1` and then try to unpack that into two variables `a` and `b` but you cant unpack a single int into two variables.

so you proabably want to just assign each value in the tuple into its own variable

```py
list1 = [(1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9), (10, 11)]

for tup_obj in list1:
    if len(tup_obj) == 2:
        a, b = tup_obj
        print(a)
        print(b)
    elif len(tup_obj) == 3:
        a, b, c = tup_obj
        print(a)
        print(b)
        print(c)
    elif len(tup_obj) == 4:
        a, b, c, d = tup_obj
        print(a)
        print(b)
        print(c)
        print(d)
```

However as you can see this doesnt scale well as you are having to code and repeat your self for every length of tuple so you might want to rethink your approach

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [(1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9), (10, 11)]

for tup_obj in list1:
    if len(tup_obj) == 2:
        a,b = tup_obj
        print(a,b)
    elif len(tup_obj) == 3:
        a,b,c = tup_obj
        print(a,b,c)
    elif len(tup_obj) == 4:
        a,b,c,d = tup_obj
        print(a,b,c,d)
```